# YOY % increase comparisons among a wide range of years

Tags: tableau-api

I am looking at compensation rates for employees and want to identify over a span of 20 years when there have been outliers (>20% increase in pay). This would be akin to a for/next loop where Id compare only two years at a time: 2000->2001 and then 2001->2002 and so forth.

How would this be achieved in tableau?

Currently I have only `if(([SalaryAnnualized 2001]/[SalaryAnnualized 2000])-1)>.2 then "Greater than 20% increase" else 0 end`

but I have too many sets of YOY's that it would be cumbersome to have 10 different calculated fields for each YOY scenario.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is at a yearly level, one way of doing this is to get the lag value of pay and year, so that you can compare them and create a calculated field which can track the increase. For example if your data was:

```
Year | Pay
2019 | $10,000
2020 | $20,000
```

Then you can get the lag of pay and at the same time creating a flag which indicates the year to year transition:

```
Year | Pay | lag(pay) | YoYFlag
2019 | $10,000 | NULL | 
2020 | $20,000 | $10,000 | 2019-2020
```

Now you can simply compare the pay and the lag pay value to get what you are looking for. If you need additional details on how to get the information from the previous row, the following link would be helpful:

https://community.tableau.com/thread/136805

Unfortunately, this methodology would fall apart, if your data is not at a year level. Hope this helps.